# check for duplicate properties in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, njsonschema

We are working on a .Net core based web api application and for this we have a requirement to validate incoming request body which is `JSON` format against the c# based type.
We are at this point evaluating `NJsonSchema` library to see if it throws duplicate property error.
But looks like it doesnt support this validation. We also checked `JSON` schema validator from `NewtonSoft` but seems like it doesnt support duplicate property validations either.

Below is the minimized code using `NJsonSchema` that we use -

```
using NewtonSoft.Json;
public class MyRequest
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and when we pass a JSON object like this -

```
{"name":"abc","name":"xyz"}
```

We need our JSON validator to throw error for `duplicate property`
Our example test looks like this -

```
[Test]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SchemaValidation_WithDuplicateProperty_Async()
        {
            var jsonString = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Data//JsonWithDuplicateProperty.json");
            var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<MyRequest>();
            var errors = schema.Validate(jsonString);
            Assert.That(errors.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
```

So my question - Has anyone done this in the past? Or are there any libraries for `.net core` that provides `JSON` validation for duplicate properties and/or can this be done using `NJsonSchema` or `NewtonSoft`.

Comment: The funny thing about this is it's legal according to [RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159#section-4) . It say's: *The names within an object SHOULD be unique.* Also worth mentioning, [JamesNK](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/931) says "There is no way in Json.NET to restrict them. It will use the last value.", interesting question BTW.

Comment: Looking a little further it seems using the [JsonLoadSettings](https://www.google.com/search?q=JsonLoadSettings) may be helpful and specifically setting the `DuplicatePropertyNameHandling` [seems to throw](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JsonLoadSettings_DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.htm) in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

As @zaggler notes, using Newtonsoft, you can use the `DuplicatePropertyNameHandling` enum. Unfortunately, you can't use it directly in a a call to `DeserializeObject` (in the `JsonSerializerSettings`); it has to be used in a JToken Reader. See this discussion thread for more details:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/931

Here is a method that wraps the action up in a `DeserializeObject`-esque way:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{""name"":""abc"",""name"":""xyz""}";

        var objA = DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings(), DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Ignore);
        Console.WriteLine(".Ignore: " + objA.Name);
        
        var objB = DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings(), DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Replace);
        Console.WriteLine(".Replace: " + objB.Name);
        
        var objC = DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings(), DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error);
        Console.WriteLine(".Error: " + objC.Name); // throws error before getting here
}
    public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json, JsonSerializerSettings settings, DuplicatePropertyNameHandling duplicateHandling)
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(json))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            jsonTextReader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
            JsonLoadSettings loadSettings = new JsonLoadSettings { 
                DuplicatePropertyNameHandling = duplicateHandling
            };
            var jtoken = JToken.ReadFrom(jsonTextReader, loadSettings);
            return jtoken.ToObject<T>(jsonSerializer);
        }
    }
}
public class MyRequest
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

> .Ignore: abc

> .Replace: xyz

> Run-time exception (line 31): Property with
> the name 'name' already exists in the current JSON object. Path
> 'name', line 1, position 21.

See:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EfpzZu